After connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError
I'm having difficulty installing Matplotlib package.
This is the errors:
 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/17/91/febbb6c1063ae05a62fdbe038c2917b348b1b35f0482cee4738e6870a44a/matplotlib-3.9.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/17/91/febbb6c1063ae05a62fdbe038c2917b348b1b35f0482cee4738e6870a44a/matplotlib-3.9.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)"))


This says your computer couldn't reach the server.  Have you tried it again?  Do you have an Internet connection from that computer?

yup my connectionis alright,

i have just installed numpy and there was no problem

And did you try matplotlib again?  What command are you typing?
